# How to count affected records in access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to get how many records were affected by a query, to know if it succeeds, if it doesn't I'll run another query.

I'm getting the parameter from a form that supposes to open the query and check

```
UPDATE attendance SET attendance.[attendance days] = [Forms]![attendace updater]![days]+[attendance days], 
attendance.[attendance hours] = [Forms]![attendace updater]]![hours]+[attendance hours]
WHERE (((attendance.[id])=[Forms]![attendace updater]]![id]) AND ((attendance.year)= 
[Forms]![attendace updater]]![year]) AND ((attendance.month)=[Forms]![attendace updater]]! 
[month]));
```

In the attendance table: month is a number, year is a number, attendance days is a number, attendance hours is a number, but id is a text...

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btn_Click()

    'create reference to you database object
    Dim myDb As dao.Database
    Set myDb = CurrentDb

    'create ref to query definition object within scope of database object
    Dim qdf as QueryDef
    Set qdf = myDb.QueryDefs("queryName")

    qdf.Execute
    MsgBox qdf.RecordsAffected

End Sub
```

If the db.execute is expecting a parameter it's probably because it's not escaping a quote properly.

Comment: Can you help me quote right? I've posted the query code

Comment: UPDATE attendance SET attendance.[attendance days] = [Forms]![attendace updater]![days]+[attendance days], 
attendance.[attendance hours] = [Forms]![attendace updater]]![hours]+[attendance hours]
WHERE ((('attendance.[id]')='[Forms]![attendace updater]]![id]') AND ((attendance.year)= 
[Forms]![attendace updater]]![year]) AND ((attendance.month)=[Forms]![attendace updater]]! 
[month]));

Comment: As a separate note i wouldn't normally recommend a text value as an id. I find that using the built in autonumber covers the majority of my uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to see how many records WILL BE affected before running the query instead of just how may were affected after you run it you can use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM [MyTable] WHERE <Same WHERE clause as the UPDATE I am testing>
```

For the specific query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
FROM attendance
WHERE (((attendance.[id])=[Forms]![attendace updater]]![id]) AND ((attendance.year)= [Forms]![attendace updater]]![year]) AND ((attendance.month)=[Forms]![attendace updater]]![month]))
```

**Edit**:

From `VBA`, you can use `DCount`. The exmple below assumes you are running the `VBA` in the context of the `[attendace updater]` form:

```
DCount("*","attendance","id='" & Me.id & "' AND year=" & Me.year & " AND month=" & Me.month)
```

Comment: I don't know why but this isn't working, how should I run it? as a separate query or just with an execution?  is it possible that the whole query is wrong because of the types of the variables?

Comment: To run it you have to open your form and put data in the fields that the query is looking for (id, month, year), then create a new query, go to SQL view and paste the code.

Comment: Is it possible to get the result of the number of the affected records into a variable I can work with, in VBA?